# How to implement Newton's method for optimization in a reliable way.

Tags: optimization, newton-raphson, hessian-matrix, non-convex-optimization

I'm trying to implement Newton's method for optimization. I want to find the local minima of a non-convex function (specifically a negative log likelihood) of $m$ variables where $m\sim 10$.

Here is my formulation:

$\mathbf{x_t}\in \mathbb{R}^m$

$H(\mathbf{x_t}) = \nabla^2f(\mathbf{x_t})$ (*Hessian matrix* computed at point $\mathbf{x_t}$ for function $f$)

$\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x_t}) = \nabla f(\mathbf{x_t})$  (*Gradient vector* computed at point $\mathbf{x_t}$ for function $f$)

Update rule:

$$
\mathbf{x}_{t + 1} = \mathbf{x}_t - H^{-1}(\mathbf{x_t})\cdot \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x_t})
$$

Since my function is non-convex I have to check at each time step if $H(\mathbf{x_t})$ is definite-positive (i.e. if it is locally convex) or not and , in that case, compute the update.

My actual implementation has the following  pseudo-code:

```
x_new = SOME_INITIAL_POINT
ftol = 1e-5
fdiff = + INF

while (fdiff > ftol)

    x_old = x_new
    g = gradient(x_old)
    H = hessian(x_old)

    if isPositiveDefinite(H)
        x_new = computeNewtonRaphsonUpdate(x_old,H,g)
    else
        x_new = computeGradientDescentUpdate(x_old,g)

    fdiff = abs(f(x_new) - f(x_old))
```

This implementation kinda works but it is extremely slow when used with some datasets, this is due to the fact that ***most of the time we end up in the Gradient Descent branch*** and the learning rates that I use are not optimal for each dataset I'm trying to test the code with. Moreover there's a ***huge scale difference*** between first parameter (which can assume values between $\sim 200$ and $\sim 18000$) and the others (which are just AR coefficients between e.g. $-2.5$ and $2.5$). For instance a "good" set of learning rates I use is $50$ for the first parameter and $0.0000005$ for the others. Of course this is not the way to go since I can't just hardcode this learning rates.

So, given that the computation of both the *gradient* vector and *hessian* matrix is correct ( I tested both with finite-difference approximations), I have two questions:

- In my actual implementation, sometimes even if the eigenvalues are positive the update rule gives me a new point $\mathbf{x}_{t+1}$ where $f(\mathbf{x}_{t+1}) > f(\mathbf{x}_{t})$. Could this happen or it is likely a numerical problem of my implementation? (e.g. some value overflowed / underflowed)
- Here is instead my main question: I saw that there are some ways of adjusting the Hessian in the [Compute Newton's direction section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) in order to always make it definite-positive, what would be the best way to modify my Hessian and handle my scale-related problems in this specific case? I would need really reliable results with ***as few iterations as possible***.

Edit:
Apparently by adding the line-search approach proposed by @LinAlg most of the time we end up in the Newton method, however since it always chooses a learning rate of e.g. 0.002 the number of iterations needed to find the local minimum is $\sim 800$.

Comment: Read the caveats section of wiki.

Comment: add a line search step to the computeNewtonRaphsonUpdate to avoid a worse function value

Comment: Thank @LinAlg, the line search step solved the first issue I had, however I still have problems on how to exploit the Hessian information to compute a reasonable direction even when the function is not locally convex

Comment: @ИванКарамазов Do you have a special test function to compare results?

Comment: Not really, the problem is that depending on the starting point it may spend either 10000 iterations or 50 iterations to find the global minimum. I just have to find a way to properly treat the different scale of the first parameter w.r.t. to the other ones, by know I just hardcoded a huge learning rate (for the gradient descent branch) for the first parameter and a really tiny learning rate, but I think this is a terrible way of handling the problem (and it kinda works just with some datasets)